# Feeding JSON into Dynatable after user submission via Deform (Pyramid)

Tags: json, ajax, pyramid, dynatable, deform

I'm building a webpage which takes user input and returns a table based on information in my backend. I'm using the web framework Pyramid. My current approach is the following:

1. Create a Colander Schema and a Deform form object that is rendered using a Chameleon template.
2. Once the user hits submit, validate the submission and use the input to generate a list of dictionaries.
3. Encode this result into JSON and feed it to dynatable.js
4. Display the dynatable below my submission form

Steps 3 and 4 are where I'm having an issue. I don't know what I need to do to expose my list of dictionaries to dynatable. I've read the Pyramid Quick Tutorial, so I have an idea of how to do simple AJAX with a JSON renderer, but I have no idea how to implement this into my current situation.

To give a better idea, my function for processing Deform input is as follows (part of the function and template is adapted from the Deform sample provided on the official Github repo):

```
@view_config(route_name='query_log', renderer='templates/form.pt') 
def query_log(request):

schema = Device().bind(request=request)

# Create a styled button with some extra Bootstrap 3 CSS classes
process_btn = deform.form.Button(name='process', title="Process")
form = deform.form.Form(schema, buttons=(process_btn,), use_ajax=True)

# User submitted this form
if request.method == "POST":
    if 'process' in request.POST:

        try:
            appstruct = form.validate(request.POST.items())

            # Save form data from appstruct
            print("Enter ID:", appstruct["ID"])
            print("Enter date:", appstruct["date"])

            # This variable is what I want to feed to dynatable
            results = parse_log(appstruct["ID"], appstruct["date"].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
            json.dumps(results)

            # Create ppoup
            request.session.flash('Returning Results.')

            # Redirect to the page shows after succesful form submission
            return HTTPFound("/")

        except deform.exception.ValidationFailure as e:
            # Render a form version where errors are visible next to the fields,
            # and the submitted values are posted back
            rendered_form = e.render()
else:
    # Render a form with initial default values
    rendered_form = form.render()

return {
    # This is just rendered HTML in a string
    # and can be embedded in any template language
    "rendered_form": rendered_form,
}
```

How would I go about passing this results variable via JSON to Dynatable and have the table rendered below the form?

Comment: What does `parse_log` do? What should the sample JSON look like?

Comment: `parse_log` just takes in the user input (id and date) and generates a list of dictionaries by parsing a log file. A sample result with two dictionaries would look like this: `[{"date": "2018-11-18", "time": "00:00:08", "id": "B5:22:EA:40:00:6B", "val": "989", "area": "base1"}, {"date": "2018-11-18", "time": "00:20:48", "id": "2F:61:C1:9C:84:FA", "val": "9", "area": "base4"}]`. This what I want to feed to dynatable.js (https://www.dynatable.com/).

Comment: I think my answer below will get you started. You can modify it to include other fields. I would recommend, however, that you use persistent storage (a database) to save the submitted records first, then separately perform a query. There are examples in the Pyramid docs for that.

Comment: The only reason I haven't opted to use persistent storage yet is because my user input just seems too trivial to require it. The only thing I need input for is to generate a query to load a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try baby steps first.

After validation is successful in your `try` block:

```
try:
    appstruct = form.validate(request.POST.items())
    # following depends on structure of data you need
    results = dict("id" = appstruct["ID"],
                   "date" = appstruct["date"].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    data = json.dumps(results)
    return dict(data=data)
```

And in the target template, accept the `data` parameter, rendering to taste.

Once you have that in place, then you can work on how to pass `data` via an XHR request, which will depend on your choice of JavaScript library.